# How to prevent pointer pass through in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a unordered list over a text, like:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
  <ul>
    <li>OK</li>
  </ul>
</a>
```

The unorder list is positioned absolute above the text using css

```
a {
  position:relative;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

Then I use jQuery's .on function to make li respond to click:

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

However, when I click on li, the link in a is also clicked and makes me go to google.com.

How can I prevent the link in a when I click on li?

The demo can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/jfq8L/

Comment: The mouse action does not pass through in chrome...

Comment: So what is the point of wrapping an `ul` element with an `a`nchor?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/jfq8L/5/ - @ZhengmingYing

Comment: I need a block element at the top-left of an inline element. So the layout needs to be unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: It works! Although stopPropagation also seems to work, but in my browser only preventDefault works.

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is to stop the event from bubbling up the tree. You can do that with stopPropagation()

And your can bind the event directly to the li, you only need to delegate it if it isn't there on pageload.

```
$('li').on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: This works great! But if one html element is positioned above another, why is it still necessary to `stopPropagation`? Shouldn't propagation only "pass through" to elements beneath if `pointer-events: none` is set?

Answer (score 3):

You have a wrong markup, `a` is an inline element and `ul` is a block level element. You cannot nest inline elements in block level elements

Comment: Would you still need to do a{display:block} in that case.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to detect a click on the li element but stop the event going through to the a.

You are going to want to separate out the event listener for the li and use

```
$('li').on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

here is an edit of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epwec/1/

Clicking on the **a** directly fires its event listener but clicking on the **li** only fires the li's event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a ul li').click(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

or

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
```

or

```
 $('li').click(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
});
```